# app install failed no code signature found on device while run pefectly fine on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i am using Firebase firestore in app and i have configured it right. When i run the app in simulator (iphone X, 8plus, 6) it run fine and i can do my work. but when i try to run on iphone 5 it give me this error.

```
App installation failed
No code signature found
```

device is running ios 9.3 and the target for project is 9.0 and also pods.

I have automatically signed the profile with my apple account. Currently no dev program is active in this account.

Also when i remove the pod of firebase and firestore app is running on the device.
Am i doing something wrong in order to run this app on device ?

If anyone faced this issue and found solution let me know.

Xcode version: 9.4

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested to update to xcode 10 and ironically it worked. I am not sure what was wrong with v9.4, maybe issue with the latest firebase sdk. Maybe older version could have solved the issue and made the build in device.

Comment: older firebase version